# error sending header, express comparison code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I wondered. And in general, I need help.

```
app.get('/admin', async (req,res) => {
    let tq = await User.findOne({ where: { link: req.params.userId } })
       // if (tq.status === req.originalUrl.split('/')[1])
     //myname(req, res)
       return res.render('/admin')
    // } else {
    //     res.end('w')
    // }
}
```

if I do this, then I will not get mistakes. (spoiler: cors on)

```
async function myname(req, res) {
    let tq = await User.findOne({ where: { link: req.params.userId } })
    if (tq.status === req.originalUrl.split('/')[1]) {
        next()
    } else {
        res.end('w')
    }
}
//and I will connect it to the code above (imagine that there are no crutches, a regular render of the page
```

then we get an error of something type: `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

what's my problem? Do I have to use conditional operators everywhere?...

Comment: I don't think you should put `return` before `res.render` and also you should pass `next` parameter before calling it.

Comment: You can't call both `res.end()` and then `res.render()`, that could be happening if you're calling `myname()`

Comment: @NickParsons what should I do then?

Comment: Don't call `res.render()` if you call `res.end()` within `myname()`. You can return a boolean from `myname()` to indicate to your calling code if you called `res.end()` within `myname`, otherwise you can call `res.end()` from within your `/admin` callback based on the boolean you returned.

Comment: It's still not clear to me if that's your actual issue though, since in your question you've commented out `// myname(req, res)` which means it won't be running and so it won't produce the error you're saying you're getting

Comment: @NickParsons on conditional statements in the code block, it works, but I want to put it into the function if false, which would refuse to work further either res.end or res.redirect and so on, that there would be no static

Comment: honestly, I still haven't figured out how it could be implemented by me